# Lightning sync test error

Tags: lightning

I have configured a Lightning Sync Connection to an Exchange Server Account provided by the client.

They have configured Exchange 2017 in their server, but when I try to make a test connection in Lightning Sync, it shows the next message :

> We can't connect with your email server using the email address you provided.

But when I try to make a test connection with an email address that has Exchange2010_SP2, at least shows an error that says something like:

> We don't support the Email's Exchange version you have provided to us.

Why do I get these errors? How can I fix or work around them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else experiments the same issues I had, the link below helped me a lot (I was able to resolve the issue)

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ials